# Modify node text within xsl copy-of

Tags: xslt

I have a xml document which looks like

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns="fst" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
<AccountServer e-dtype="int">3</AccountServer>    
</Header>
<Response>
<ResponseList e-dtype="list">
  <Response>
    <RequestId e-dtype="string">ServiceOrderGetRef</RequestId>
    <RequestObjName e-dtype="string">ServiceOrder</RequestObjName>
    <ServiceOrder>          
      <CreateDt e-dtype="dateTime">2014-03-01 00:00:00</CreateDt>
      <CreateWho e-dtype="string">vc</CreateWho>          
      <WorkflowStartDt e-dtype="dateTime">2014-04-01 00:00:00</WorkflowStartDt>          
    </ServiceOrder>
  </Response>
  <Response>
    <ComponentList e-dtype="list"/>
    <Count e-dtype="int">0</Count>
    <RequestId e-dtype="string">ComponentFindRef</RequestId>
    <RequestObjName e-dtype="string">Component</RequestObjName>
    <TotalCount e-dtype="int">0</TotalCount>
  </Response>
  <Response>
    <Count e-dtype="int">0</Count>
    <CustomerContractList e-dtype="list"/>
    <RequestId e-dtype="string">CustomerContractRef</RequestId>
    <RequestObjName e-dtype="string">CustomerContract</RequestObjName>
    <TotalCount e-dtype="int">0</TotalCount>
  </Response>
  <Response>
    <Count e-dtype="int">0</Count>
    <ProductList e-dtype="list"/>
    <RequestId e-dtype="string">ProductRef</RequestId>
    <RequestObjName e-dtype="string">Product</RequestObjName>
    <TotalCount e-dtype="int">0</TotalCount>
  </Response>
  <Response>
    <Count e-dtype="int">0</Count>
    <NrcList e-dtype="list"/>
    <RequestId e-dtype="string">NrcFindRef</RequestId>
    <RequestObjName e-dtype="string">Nrc</RequestObjName>
    <TotalCount e-dtype="int">0</TotalCount>
  </Response>
  </ResponseList>
  </Response>
  </Request>
```

I am using `copy-of` function to copy node ServiceOrder within another xml document

I want to modify text of node `WorkFlowStartDt` and `CreateDt` and then do a `copy-of`. How can I do this?
My copied serviceorder node should look like this after modifing text. Below is the result xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
 <Header>
  <OperatorName e-dtype="string">ws</OperatorName>
  <ApplicationName e-dtype="string">ws</ApplicationName>
</Header>
<CustomerUdtRequest>
<RequestList e-dtype="list">
  <LogicalServiceOrder>
    <RequestId e-dtype="string">MyExistingOrder</RequestId>
    <LogicalServiceOrderPreProcess>
      <Fetch e-dtype="boolean">true</Fetch>
      <Order>
        <AccountInternalId e-dtype="int">12345</AccountInternalId>
        <Key>
          <OrderId e-dtype="numeric">12345678</OrderId>
        </Key>
      </Order>
      <ServiceOrderList e-dtype="list">
        <ServiceOrder  xmlns="fst" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   
       instance">          
              <CreateDt e-dtype="dateTime">2014-03-02 00:00:00</CreateDt>
              <CreateWho e-dtype="string">vc</CreateWho>          
              <WorkflowStartDt e-dtype="dateTime">2014-05-01 00:00:00</WorkflowStartDt>          
    </ServiceOrder>
      </ServiceOrderList>
    </LogicalServiceOrderPreProcess>
  </LogicalServiceOrder>
  </RequestList>
</CustomerUdtRequest>
</Request>
```

Below is my xslt processor file

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>    
<xsl:template match="/">
<Request>
<Header>
<OperatorName e-dtype="string">ws</OperatorName>
<ApplicationName e-dtype="string">ws</ApplicationName>
</Header>
<CustomerUdtRequest>
<RequestList e-dtype="list">                    
<LogicalServiceOrder>
<RequestId e-dtype="string">MyExistingOrder</RequestId>
<LogicalServiceOrderPreProcess>                         <Order>                                         <AccountInternalId e-dtype="int">
<xsl:value-of   
      select="/Request/Response/ResponseList/Response/ServiceOrder/AccountInternalId"/>
                                        </AccountInternalId>                                            <Key>                                           <OrderId e-dtype="numeric">                                                 <xsl:value-of select="/Request/Response/ResponseList/Response/ServiceOrder/OrderId"/>
                                            </OrderId>
                                        </Key>
                                    </Order>
                                    <ServiceOrderList e-dtype="list">                                   
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="/Request/Response/ResponseList/Response/ServiceOrder"/>
                                    </ServiceOrderList>
                                </LogicalServiceOrderPreProcess>
                            </LogicalServiceOrder>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </RequestList>
                </CustomerUdtRequest>
            </Request>
        </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to modify text of node WorkFlowStartDt and CreateDt and then do
>   a copy-of.

That would be an unnecessary complication. You can modify nodes **while** you add them to the output tree.

Since you essentially want to copy everything "as is" except two nodes, it would be best to start with an *identity transform template*, then add an "exception" template for the two specific nodes that need modifying (one template for both, since the modification is identical).:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transformation -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CreateDt | WorkFlowStartDt">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('**', ., '**')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

In response to the edited question, try this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="fst"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<Request>
    <Header>
        <OperatorName e-dtype="string">ws</OperatorName>
        <ApplicationName e-dtype="string">ws</ApplicationName>
    </Header>
    <CustomerUdtRequest>
        <RequestList e-dtype="list">                    
            <LogicalServiceOrder>
                <RequestId e-dtype="string">MyExistingOrder</RequestId>
                <LogicalServiceOrderPreProcess>
                    <Order>
                        <AccountInternalId e-dtype="int">
                            <!-- THIS DOESN'T POINT TO ANY EXISTING NODE!! -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="ns:Request/ns:Response/ns:ResponseList/ns:Response/ns:ServiceOrder/ns:AccountInternalId"/>
                        </AccountInternalId>
                        <Key>
                            <OrderId e-dtype="numeric">
                                <!-- THIS DOESN'T POINT TO ANY EXISTING NODE!! -->
                                <xsl:value-of select="ns:Request/ns:Response/ns:ResponseList/ns:Response/ns:ServiceOrder/ns:OrderId"/>
                            </OrderId>
                        </Key>
                    </Order>

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ns:Request/ns:Response/ns:ResponseList/ns:Response/ns:ServiceOrder"/>

                </LogicalServiceOrderPreProcess>
            </LogicalServiceOrder>
        </RequestList>
    </CustomerUdtRequest>
</Request>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="ns:ServiceOrder">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ns:CreateWho"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns:CreateDt | ns:WorkflowStartDt"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns:CreateDt | ns:WorkflowStartDt">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('**', ., '**')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input (minus the illegal opening comment), the following result is obtained:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
   <Header>
      <OperatorName e-dtype="string">ws</OperatorName>
      <ApplicationName e-dtype="string">ws</ApplicationName>
   </Header>
   <CustomerUdtRequest>
      <RequestList e-dtype="list">
         <LogicalServiceOrder>
            <RequestId e-dtype="string">MyExistingOrder</RequestId>
            <LogicalServiceOrderPreProcess>
               <Order>
                  <AccountInternalId e-dtype="int"/>
                  <Key>
                     <OrderId e-dtype="numeric"/>
                  </Key>
               </Order>
               <ServiceOrder xmlns="fst" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                  <CreateWho e-dtype="string">vc</CreateWho>
                  <CreateDt e-dtype="dateTime">**2014-03-01 00:00:00**</CreateDt>
                  <WorkflowStartDt e-dtype="dateTime">**2014-04-01 00:00:00**</WorkflowStartDt>
               </ServiceOrder>
            </LogicalServiceOrderPreProcess>
         </LogicalServiceOrder>
      </RequestList>
   </CustomerUdtRequest>
</Request>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your reply. Actually original xml document has got lot of additional nodes which I do not want. That is the reason I want to just copy the ServiceOrder node and then modify contents within that node.

Comment: Now you tell me. Please edit your question and provide an **indicative** example of the input. Make sure we understand how many ServceOrder elements can be in the root Request, and *where* exactly could any unwanted nodes be located.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question with input and output xml. I am able to generate the output xml but not able to modify the text of node WorkflowStartDt  and CreateDt

Comment: Sorry, but I am even more confused now, because I don't see how one maps into the other. Perhaps you should also post your existing XSLT stylesheet. I also notice that your source has a namespace and your result doesn't. Which is not possible if you have used `copy-of`.

Comment: Please find xslt stylesheet in my question. I have corrected the response xml and added namespace now.

Comment: @user3366906 I have added another version to my answer. I hope this solves your problem. You're not making it easy: your stylesheet has an extra `</xsl if>` in it, and some paths that point to nowhere in your XML.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help and sorry for some extra code and if which caused confusion.